# MAPR M7 hbase cluster is not populating .META. table

Tags: hbase, emr, mapr

I was finding the reason that why MAPR M7 EMR cluster is not populating HBASE .META. table. I tried to fix using hbck command also but still got no success. Any help will be highly appriciated

Answer (score 0):

MapR M7 does not implement the .META. tables. It doesn't need to. The table metadata is stored in a format native to the mapr filesystem. Perhaps you can use alternate ways to fulfill your requirement than querying .META. directly. Can you elaborate on the need for META in your application ?